# Redirect to new page on parent window from iframe after ASP.NET PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, redirect

I have a simple ASP.NET web form on a page, which is contained in an `iframe` on another page.

After this form has been submitted, I want the parent page, which contains the `iframe`, to be redirected to a particular URL.

How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
window.opener.location.href='www.domain.com'
```

But `window.opener` returns a `null` value. I think this is to do with the PostBack.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp) object (**window.opener.location.href**) instead to accomplish this task.